# SQL Count valid Transactions per User

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get a list of customers that made a specific amount of valid transactions between two dates.

```
SELECT
  customer.customer_id,
  COUNT(
    CASE WHEN transaction.transaction_date>="2010-01-01" 
      THEN 1 
    ELSE NULL 
    END
  ) AS Total
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN transaction ON customer.customer_id = transaction.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
HAVING (Total>=min_transactions AND Total<=max_transactions)
```

This doesn't return anything. By removing the CASE in the COUNT(..), it returns the amount of transactions per user, but it also contains invalid and out of range transactions.

Isn't the CASE loop supposed to work like that in the COUNT?

Is it a better idea to count only the transactions, without merging the two tables?

(Using MySQL)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Try `sum` instead of `count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the query that you want:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, COUNT(t.customer_id) as Total
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     transaction t
     ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id AND
        t.transaction_date >= '2010-01-01'
GROUP BY c.customer_id
HAVING Total >= min_transactions AND Total <= max_transactions;
```

Notes:

- Conditions on the *second* table in a `LEFT JOIN` usually belong in the `ON` clause.
- Use single quotes for date and string constants.  Double quotes can be used to escape identifiers.
- The `count()` is counting from the second table.  If there are no matches, the count will be `0`.
- A `LEFT JOIN` is needed only if `min_transactions` is ever `0`.

Comment: Is there a reason for an anonymous downvote on this?

Comment: Thank you @Gordon ! It works exactly as i needed. (The downvote isn't from me)